# Formulating the Integral for Calculating the Mass of a Plate with Given Density

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, area

I am seeking guidance on formulating the integral to calculate the mass of a plate with density $d(x, y) = x + y$, whose shape is defined by the following figure:

[image]

I made the next:

The mass $M$ of the plate is calculated through the double integral of the density $d(x, y)$ over the region $R$ of the plate. In this case, the integral is expressed as:

$ M = \iint_R (x + y) \ dA $

Where $dA$ represents the differential area element. The region $R$ is defined by the parabola and the aforementioned lines. To describe the region, we can use polar coordinates considering the symmetry of the parabola. Thus, the integral transforms to polar coordinates as:

$ M = \int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_2} \int_{r_1(\theta)}^{r_2(\theta)} (r \cos(\theta) + r \sin(\theta)) \ r \ dr \ d\theta $

Here, $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ are the angles corresponding to the lines $y = -x$ and $y = x$, respectively, and$r_1(\theta)$ and $r_2(\theta)$ are the functions describing the parabola in polar coordinates.

I would appreciate any additional guidance or corrections in the formulation of the integral. Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: I really don't think polar coordinates is useful here. There's no rotational symmetry to the region.

Comment: I see. But how then? In Cartesian coordinates?

Comment: That's how I would do it. Have you found the equations for the curves and lines bounding the region?

Comment: I think they are $x = y^2 + 5$, $y = 2x$ and $y = -2x$

Comment: To @Ayesca: Do you have some progress on this problem?